# Finding rotation/heading of JPEG image

Tags: python, gdal, georeferencing

I have a series of JPEG images taken from a UAV that have geospatial info associated with them. I'm trying to pull out that info in python but I'm having some trouble. In the past when I've done this the images are either GeoTIFF files that have all the necessary info in the header, or they had an associated world file (.tfw or .jpw) that contained the location of the top left pixel, along with a rotation or heading so you can what direction the image is facing. The image I'm using right now doesn't have a world file. I'm able to use GDAL to pull out the lat/long of the upper left pixel, but north isn't up in this image and I can't find that information in the image.

So far I've mostly used gdal:

```
src = gdal.Open(img_path)
src.GetMetadata_Dict()
```

With gdal I can easily get the corner location:

[image]

Which I can easily parse to degrees instead of minutes/seconds. But I'm not seeing any rotation or heading information. Similarly with PIL I can pull out the corner lat/long, but I'm not able to find what direction is up in the image. But the information must be in there because when I throw it into a GIS the image appears correctly geolocated and rotated.

Does anybody know how I can pull that information using Python?

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. Do you have an image you are able to share? In addition, you can give [gdalinfo](https://gdal.org/programs/gdalinfo.html) a try.

Comment: gdalinfo pulls up useful information, however as far as the location information goes all that's there is the same upper left corner coordinate. I'll see what I can do about sharing one of the images.